# Loading image from sqllite does not appear

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-imageview

I have an app that loads data from a sqllite database, then converts the data to appropriate formats so it could pass on the data to fragment tabs.
Everything works fine except for the images. 
In the DB images are stored in full path, for example `R.drawable.muntjakas` and the images are available in the resource drawable folder.
The app pulls the data from the db and then converts it to int format so it could be passed on. Eclipse is not giving me any errors, but when the app loads images are not displayed. My xml files have the image id set up and displays the images if I assign the values manually for example

```
flag = new int[] { R.drawable.muntjakas,.... };
```

What's the problem?
`fragmenttab1.java` class that loads data from sql and converts it:

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends SherlockFragment {

    ListView list;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;

       private static final String DB_NAME = "animalsDB.sqllite3";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "animals";
        private static final String ANIMAL_ID = "_id";
        private static final String ANIMAL_NAME = "name";
        private static final String ANIMAL_PIC = "pic";
        public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {ANIMAL_ID, ANIMAL_NAME,ANIMAL_PIC };

        private SQLiteDatabase database;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmenttab1, container,
                false);

        ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(getActivity(), DB_NAME);
            database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
        Cursor cursor = getAllRows();


        ArrayList<String> nameArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> picArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(cursor.moveToFirst(); cursor.moveToNext(); cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            nameArray.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ANIMAL_NAME)));
            picArray.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ANIMAL_PIC)));
        }
        final String[] name = (String[]) nameArray.toArray(new String[nameArray.size()]);
        final Integer[] pic = (Integer[]) picArray.toArray(new Integer[picArray.size()]);

        final int[] flag =  new int[pic.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < pic.length; i++ ) {
           flag[i] = pic[i];
        }

        // Locate the ListView in fragmenttab1.xml
        list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Pass results to ListViewAdapter Class
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), name, flag);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Capture clicks on ListView items
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SingleItemView.class);

                // Pass all data country
                i.putExtra("country", name);
                // Pass all data flag
                i.putExtra("flag", flag);
                // Pass a single position
                i.putExtra("position", position);
                // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                startActivity(i);

            }});
        return rootView;
    }

    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c =  database.query(true, TABLE_NAME, ALL_KEYS, 
                            where, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

}
```

My `listViewAdapter.java` class that should load the data on the screen:

```
package kf.kaunozoo;
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Declare Variables
    Context context;
    String[] country;
    int[] flag;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, String[] country, int[] flag) {
        this.context = context;     
        this.country = country;
        this.flag = flag;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return country.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Declare Variables

        TextView txtcountry;
        ImageView imgflag;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml

        txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
        // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
        imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);

        // Capture position and set to the TextViews        
        txtcountry.setText(country[position]);

        // Capture position and set to the ImageView
        imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? All answers are appreciated

Comment: first of all if your data is in sqlite db use one of CursorAdapter subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem once in one of my apps, however, what I did was, I saved unique ids for each drawable in database as I had limited images. While displaying I wrote a small function where I used `switch` statement to check for each id from database and then loaded images accordingly in `ImageView`.

However, when you have lots of images, try to use below function, where you can provide image names dynamically from database.

```
// image from res/drawable
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("your_image_name", 
        "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Also, you may try the solution given at this [blog](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/2009/12/dynamically-retrieving-resources-in.html).